# C algorithm about returning a number

Tags: c++

I have this algorithm

```
int oglinda(int n)
{
    if(n>9)
    {

        cout << n%10;
        oglinda(n/10);
    }
}
```

and it returns a number from right to left for example for 341=>143.
Here's the problem:
When the algorithm reaches the last number (which is < 9) it shouldn't receive it's value but instead it does. How comes that when the number is less than 9?

Comment: Turn on all the warnings of your compiler. Your function says it returns a value, but there is no value returned!!!

Comment: Also choose your language wisely: `cout` is not part of the C language; `<<` is shift left ;)

Comment: Your code is C++ but tagged with C?

Comment: i made a mistake so what?don't be so harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using the code below:

```
int oglinda(int n)
{
    if(n>9)
    {
        cout<<n%10;
        oglinda(n/10);
    } else{
        cout<<n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code: If you are using C compiler

```
 int oglinda(int n) {
     if(n>9) {
         printf("%d",n%10);    // Your tag is C and not C++
         return oglinda(n/10);
     } else {
         printf("%d",n);
     }
 return 0;    // You have to add return at the end of function
 }
```

Or Try with this code: If you are using C++ compiler

```
 int oglinda(int n) {
     if(n>9) {
         cout << n%10;    
         return oglinda(n/10);
     } else {
         cout << n;
     }
 return 0;    // You have to add return at the end of function
 }
```